# "NSApp.activate" in front of another app in fullscreen mode

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, focus, nsapplication

You can use following code to bring your app window to focus when a specific event was triggered, e.g. a global hotkey was pressed or a tea timer has expired:

```
NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
myView?.view.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self);
```

Problem: If this code executes while another app is the fullscreen mode, the user will be pushed back to the first desktop. This is a bad user experience because it interrupts the user.

How would I present my view just in front of the currently active fullscreen app?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use  `NSWindow.Level` to stay above other apps.

**Set Window Level**:

> It controls your apps z-axis. Higher the value goes higher level.
> There are predefined values like normal, floating and all.

```swift
view.window?.level = NSWindow.Level.floating
```

But you can define your own to achieve much higher level like this

```swift
view.window?.level = NSWindow.Level(rawValue: 104) //where 104 is the window level
```

For more information about `NSWindow.Level` [check here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/level)

**Set Collection Behaviour**:

It is what let your app stays in other apps space. Refer the documentation for detailed explanation [check here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/collectionbehavior)

```swift
view.window?.collectionBehavior = [.canJoinAllSpaces, .fullScreenAuxiliary]
```

My above solution will only work if you are using `NSPanel` which is a subclass of `NSWindow`.

**Set Activation Policy:**

If you prefer to use `NSWindow`, you need to additionally set the `NSApplication.ActivationPolicy` to `.accessory` like this

```swift
NSApplication.shared.setActivationPolicy(NSApplication.ActivationPolicy.accessory)
```

> Activation Policy determines how your app can be activated.
> For more information [check here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/activationpolicy)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the window's property `collectionBehaviour` and `level`.

Use the following code to display the window:

**Swift 5**

```
NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)   
myView.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
myView.window?.collectionBehavior = .canJoinAllSpaces
myView.window?.level = NSWindow.Level.tornOffMenu
```